# make dropdown options change based on ng-grid selectedItem[0]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

First, let me say Thank you for taking the time to read this and I am sorry for not pasting my code, the work I do is on a server that doesn't have internet connection.  I think I can explain what I am asking and perhaps type out some pseudo code well enough to get my point across.

I have an html page with an angular controller.  The HTML page displays a list of items representing rows in the database using ng-grid.  The drop down displays when an item in the list is selected and the dropdown is an auto submit

```
ng-change="processOptions(dropdown_options)"
```

Selected Item is part of scope in the controller:

```
$scope.selectedItem=[];
```

The dropdown displays based on the selected item in the grid being .. well selected.

```
ng-show="selectedItem[0]"
```

The dropdown options are defined in the controller as:

```
$scope.dropdownOptions = [
    {label: "Option Blue", value: "BLUE"},        
    {label: "Option Green", value: "GREEN"},
    {label: "Option Yellow", value: "YELLOW"},
];
```

The above is working well.  Now what I would like to do is make the options conditional upon a value seen in selectedItem[0].color

When selectedItem[0].color=="BLUE" I would only want GREEN and YELLOW options to show.. and so on if color="GREEN" then only have BLUE and YELLOW appear in the options.

How do I accomplish this?  Is there another ng controller that can be triggered when selectedItem[0] is defined that calls a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I couldn't get ng-filter or filter in general to work because .. well all the examples I found filtered the list against some text.. including items that partially matched or fully matched the text.  In this case I need it to EXCLUDE exact matches.  The ng-filter suggestion headed me in the right direction and in the end a short time later I came up with the following solution that works and doesn't interfere with any of the other operations in the  tag.  This seems a bit klugey to me so if there is a better solution that does involve ng-filter please fill me in.

```
ng-options="opt.label for opt in filterOptions()"
```

Then in the controller:

```
$scope.filterOptions = function() {
    if ($scope.selectedItem[0]) {
        if ($scope.selectedItem[0].color === "GREEN") {
            $scope.dropdownOptions = [                    
                {label: "Option Blue", value: "BLUE"},    
                {label: "Option Yellow", value: "YELLOW"}
            ]
        }
        else if .....and so on {

        }
    }
    return $scope.dropdownOptions;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [ng-filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

Answer (score 1):

[ng-filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) has the functionality you need.